# Associate `.lift` files with XML syntax highlighting in Brackets

Tags: syntax-highlighting, file-types, brackets

***Cross-posted from an old unanswered Stack Overflow question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820900/associate-lift-files-with-xml-syntax-highlighting-in-brackets)).***

I'm using a `.lift` ([Lexicon Interchange FormaT](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lift-standard/)) file, which Brackets does not recognise, but, since it's basically an XML file, the syntax highlighting for that works just fine. The problem is that I have to manually tell Brackets to use XML syntax highlighting every time I open a `.lift` file. My question is, is there any way to permanently associate XML syntax highlighting with `.lift` files? (Note that simply changing the file extension from `.lift` to `.xml` is not really an optimal solution since the file needs to keep the extension `.lift` for use elsewhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Brackets, but a bit of digging gives me these links:

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support#preferences

Assuming you want to do this globally, that leads to these steps:

1. Hit Debug > Open Preferences File
2. You should see 2 panes. You should read the comments on the left-hand pane, but the left-hand pane should give you examples for all the supported settings. The right-hand pane should be your actual settings file.
3. Look for the `"language.fileExtensions"` key in the right-hand pane. If it's not there, add it to the end. Don't forget to put a trailing comma on the previous line!
4. Populate it with `{"lift": "xml"}`, to say that anything with a `.lift` extension is actually an `.xml` file.

If you've made a new entry, it should look like `"language.fileExtensions": {"lift": "xml"}`. If you're updating an existing one, it might look like:

```
"language.fileExtensions": {
  "html": "php",
  "lift": "xml"
}
```

That worked for me, hopefully you see the same.